# Passing a string from a DLL to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++-cli, parameter-passing

I have a C# application that accesses functions from an unmanaged C++ libary using a CLI DLL. My problem is that I can't get text from the C++ library to be passed through to the C# application correctly. The code I have thus far is as follows:

C#

```
[DllImport("Wrapper.dll", EntryPoint = "GetNameLength", CallingConvention = CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool _GetNameLength( int index, out int size);
[DllImport("Wrapper.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "GetName", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool _GetName( out Stringbuilder name, int size, int index);

private void TestFunction()
{
    int size = 0;
    _GetNameLength(2, out size);
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(size + 1);

    _GetName(out str, str.Capacity, 2);

    btnName.Text = str.ToString();
}
```

CLI

```
// In the header.
#define DllExport __declspec( dllexport)

extern "C" {
    DllExport bool __cdecl GetNameLength( int index, int& size);
    DllExport bool __cdecl GetName( char* name, int size, int index);
};


// In the '.cpp'.
bool __cdecl GetNameLength( int index, int& size) {
    if( gp_app == nullptr)
        return false;

    gp_app->GetNameLength( index, size);

    return true;
}

bool __cdecl GetName( char* name, int index, int size) {
    if( gp_app == nullptr)
        return false;

    const char* n = "";
    n = gp_app->GetName( index);

    name = new char[size];
    strcpy( name, n);

    return true;
}
```

C++

```
// In the header.
class App {
    void GetNameLength( int index, int& size);
    const char* GetName( int index);
};

// In the '.cpp'.
void App::GetNameLength( int index, int& size) {
    if( index >= 0 && index < gs_namesCount)
        size = strlen( gs_names[index]);
}

const char* App::GetName( int index) {
    if( index >= 0 && index < gs_namesCount)
        return gs_names[index];

    return nullptr;
}
```

I am able to debug into the DLL and I've seen that it does copy the name over correctly, even when I just use `name = const_cast<char*>( n)` (and when I use a string instead of a StringBuilder), but for some reason that value isn't getting back to C# from the DLL.

I read that a possible reason is because C++ may use ASCII characters while C# uses 16-bit characters, and that the fix for that is to include `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` so that it's marshalled correctly when it's returned to C#, but that apparently hasn't helped.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Solution**:
Use a `public ref class` instead of a namespace and declare functions using `void Foo( [Out] String^ %name)` ensuring that `using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;` is included.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a mismatch between the header and the implementation of `GetName` in your C++ portion (one takes one arg, the other two).

Comment: If you are using C++/CLI, why bother with dll exports? Use a `ref class` and you can use it just like C#.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ah, sorry, that was a typo when copying to code across.

Comment: @crashmstr Because I've not used `ref class` before and I have a decent amount of code implemented using this method. Can `ref class` use a pointer to an unmanaged C++ class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tells me you actually have a managed c++ dll.

```
if( gp_app == nullptr)
    return false;
```

If so you can export a managed class and use String as parameter to the method.

Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh699870.aspx

Comment: I tried using `String` and `StringBuilder` as parameters in my wrapper, however it then meant that I couldn't assign it with `__cdecl` (I had to use `__clrdecl`, I believe it was) which meant that it couldn't be exported for use in my C# code.

Comment: @Edward Use a ref class and call those functions from there. Then use String constructor to create the managed string.

Comment: I just tried changing to a ref class and using `name = %String( n)` and it compiled, I debugging into it and `name` was correctly updated to the correct value, but that value was still not being passed back into my C# code once it left the function.

Comment: You should declare name parameter as out String^ name

Comment: It says `'out' : undeclared indentifier` if I try and do that. Same with `ref` (but it's fine with the class being declared as `public ref class`).

Comment: My mistake, I did not do a lot of this kind of stuff. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186477/in-c-cli-how-do-i-declare-and-call-a-function-with-an-out-parameter

Comment: I've just found that if I use the ref class and instead of having the function as `void GetName( String^ name, int index)`, I have it as `String^ GetName( int index)` that it does correctly return the value to the C# code. I guess it's a solution, but I'd really like to have it as a parameter.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much, I can now finally pass text using parameters :).