# how to Call C# function(string as out parameter) from C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, com

I am working in a project in that i have a native(c++) application and a COM DLL(c# .Net).
My requirement is, form my native application I want to call a function in COM DLL, and that function returns string(out parameter).

Bellow is the code

C# COM Code....

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IUserDetais
{
    bool GetUserConfigData(out string configData);
}

[
ComVisible(true),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
GuidAttribute("GUID"),
]
public class AppUserDetais : IUserDetais
{
    public bool GetUserConfigData(out string configData)
    {
        configData = "Some JSON content.";
        reurn true;
    }
}
```

C++ code

```
void GetUserInfo(IUserDetais* pUserInfo)
{
    // TODO, How to call the function. what should be the signature in C#(the out string length can vary and how to delete the memory allocated).
    //pUserInfo->GetUserConfigData();
}
```

Can any one tell me how to to call GetUserConfigData in C++ code.

**Updated:**

C++ is not .Net code. it is C++ win32 or native code.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186477/in-c-cli-how-do-i-declare-and-call-a-function-with-an-out-parameter

Comment: Do let IntelliSense help you to fall into the pit of success, it tells you a *lot* about how to call this method properly.  You need two arguments, a BSTR* and a VARIANT_BOOL*.  Don't forget to check the HRESULT return value and SysFreeString() to release the string.

Comment: Modify definition as 
GetUserConfigData([Runtime::InteropServices::Out] string^% configData)

Comment: You have asked the wrong question. You are **not** trying to call managed code from unmanaged code. You are trying to access a **language-neutral** COM object from a programming language, that can consume COM interfaces. The answer to this question is very different from the answer to the question you asked.