# C++/CLI and .NET out string paramter

Tags: c#, c++-cli

In C#, I have this method (.net framework 2.0)

```
 public String Authenticate( String configUrl, out String tokenId)
```

I want to call it from managed c++ code
I have

```
__authenticator->Authenticate(  gcnew System::String(hostUrl),gcnew System::String(temp));
```

but the tokenId is coming back as true.

I have seen some answers talk about using ^ % in the C# but that just doesn't compile.

Comment: See `http://stackoverflow.com/a/187577/613130`... but what is the problem here? what are `temp` and `hostUrl`? What do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

With

```
public String Authenticate(String configUrl, out String tokenId)
```

this

```
__authenticator->Authenticate(
    gcnew System::String(hostUrl),
    gcnew System::String(temp)
);
```

is, in C#, equivalent (considering the signature of Authenticate) to

```
__authenticator.Authenticate(
    new String(hostUrl),
    out new String(temp)
);
```

but in C# you can't do a `out new Something`, you can only `out` to variables, fields... So in C# you would need to do:

```
String temp2 = new String(temp);

__authenticator.Authenticate(
    new String(hostUrl),
    out temp2
);
```

and, considering that the parameter is in `out` you can:

```
String temp2;

__authenticator.Authenticate(
    new String(hostUrl),
    out temp2
);
```

Now, in C++/CLI you have

```
System::String^ temp2 = gcnew System::String(temp);

__authenticator->Authenticate(
    gcnew System::String(hostUrl),
    temp2
);
```

or, knowing that `temp2` is `out` (note that the difference between `ref` and `out` is something checked only by the C# compiler, not by the C++/CLI compiler)

```
// agnostic of the out vs ref
System::String^ temp2 = nullptr;

// or knowing that temp2 will be used as out, so its value is irrelevant
// System::String^ temp2;

__authenticator->Authenticate(
    gcnew System::String(hostUrl),
    temp2
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got it, make the parameter I pass in a String^

```
CString hostUrl;
String^ temp ;
String^ error = __authenticator.get() == nullptr ? "failed to get token" : 
                 __authenticator->Authenticate(  gcnew System::String(hostUrl),temp);
```